# How to select an area and fill it with a grid in PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've to output few points in an interactively selected region of an image. I'm not familiar with PyQt to select the appropriate elements for the task. Please suggest the right way to do it. Currently, this is what I intend to do :

1. Load the image.

   > Use QImage (QPixMap?) to display the image.
2. Select a rectangular region in the image.

   > Use QRubberBand to select the region.
3. Draw a grid in the region.

   > Use QLines?
4. Make the grid points (interesctions) selectable.

   > No idea.

Any pointers to snippets using the required classes will be greatly helpful. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView` to display your scene.

1. Use `scene->addPixmap` to add the image.
2. Use `QRubberBand` to select the region as you said.
3. Use `view->mapToScene` to convert viewport coordinates obtained from `QRubberBand` to the scene coordinates.
4. Add lines using `scene->addLine`
5. Add small circle items to lines intersection points using `scene->addEllipse`. This function returns `QGraphicsEllipseItem*` object. You should use circles with (0, 0) center. Use `item->setPos` to move each circle in the proper place.
6. Use `item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable)` to make circle items selectable. You can now select items with mouse clicks.
7. Use `view->dragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag)` if you want to enable items selection using automatic `QRubberBand`.
8. Use `QGraphicsScene::selectedItems` to obtain selected items. You can then use `item->pos()` to obtain items positions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 5th point probably saved me hours of pointless pondering.